# How to retrieve buyer billing information from PayPal ExpressCheckout via NVP?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have integrated Paypal ExpressCheckout using NVP in a site but I only receive information related to the transaction via GetExpressCheckoutDetails but not the billing information such as buyer name, address. I have used the v65 of the API and PHP. Is there a way to get/retrieve buyer information when they login to PayPal and pay using ExpressCheckout ?

An example how I used it.

```
$nvpstr = '&TOKEN=' . $token . etc ...
$resArray = hash_call("GetExpressCheckoutDetails", $nvpstr);
print_r($resArray);
```

But I receive only transaction details without buyer information.

Answer (score 0):

Only the shipping information would be returned if you are requiring shipping.  The billing information is not returned.  If you are needing the billing information returned, you would need to contact PayPal Business Support or your account manager if you have one and request the option to be turned on to return the billing information.  In addition to having this turned on, you also need to pass over the variable `REQBILLINGADDRESS` in your SetExpressCheckout API call and you need to set the value to “`1`”.

REQBILLINGADDRESS
(Optional) Is 1 or 0. The value 1 indicates that you require that the buyer’s billing address on file with PayPal be returned. Setting this element will return BILLTONAME, STREET, STREET2, CITY, STATE, ZIP, and COUNTRYCODE.
Limitations: One character.