# Retrive Payer info in paypal api

Tags: php, api, paypal

I have `Capture` and `Authentification` class that works on PHP `PayPal SDK API`, is there any way to retrive `Payer` details such as email, address, phone etc.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes there is ... but you need to have a business agreement with PayPal for them to send you that data (e.g. billing address) in the first place otherwise you can only get delivery information.

Comment: So u r telling me that with transaction ID that paypal give mi, i cannot see the name and email of the payer? I need some agreement with PayPal ?I need to get Payment ID and my problem woud be resolved. Thanks

Comment: You can get *some* details (like their name and email address) but not others (billing address) without having it set up on your account with PayPal; see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072740/how-to-retrieve-buyer-billing-information-from-paypal-expresscheckout-via-nvp

Comment: I got it. Can u tell me how to get their name and email address? Thanks a lot btw

Comment: Assuming you're using NVP : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/ info about the available fields are in the **Payer Information Fields** and **PayerName (PersonNameType) Fields** sections of the docs.

Answer (score -3):

try use print_r($_POST); to view all user's post.

Comment: I have transaction ID in my database, i wanna get the payer details for invoice